# tags manager jquery plugin using typeahead

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

I want to use tags manager (jquery plugin).
Link: http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager

In the example in the site I saw that there is an option to use typeahead.

This Is what I did:

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/tagmanager/typeahead.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/tagmanager/bootstrap-tagmanager.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/tagmanager/bootstrap-tagmanager.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input type='text' class="input" data-provide="typeahead" name='tagsInput' id='tagsInput' value='' />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#tagsInput").tagsManager({
        deleteTagsOnBackspace: false,
        prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome"],
        typeahead: true,
        typeaheadAjaxSource: null,
        typeaheadSource: ["Pisa", "Rome", "Milan", "Florence", "New York", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", "Madrid"],
        blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
        blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
        hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA'
});
```

I'm gettings this error on bootstrap-tagmanager.js:62:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

What i'm doing wrong?

If I'm removing the include of typeahead.js the tags manager plugin is working but without the typeahead option.

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/F8C8c/

**OR:** 
Maybe you can recommend me a better tags manager plugin that working with autocomplate tags loaded via ajax?

**EDIT:**
I found the problem.
I should need to include bootstrap.js and not typeahead.js.

Comment: It's working in their example page http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager

Comment: I'm starting to question if there's a plugin missing.  Some JS file that needs to be there, but isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the wrong "typeahead.js" module.

You need the bootstrap-typeahead.js.

Look for it here:

https://raw.github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/master/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js

Comment: Yeah, even that plugin requires bootstrap.js.  However, just adding the plugin solves the initial problem of the prototype error.